# How to prevent screenshots in Android or React-Native app

Tags: android, react-native, screenshot, snapshot

How do I prevent a user to take screenshots in React-Native app? 
I have read in some comments on some other posted questions people saying that this line of code will prevent screenshots, but where exactly do I have to insert it?

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Or if there is any other way just let me know.

**P.S: I am interested to know only for Android platform.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert it in `MainActivity.java`, In your `MainActivity.java` override `onCreate` method.

```
package com.reactnativepreventscreenshot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "reactnativepreventscreenshot";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://github.com/julekgwa/react-native-prevent-screenshot)

Comment: I dont understand why everyone states that this should be in MainActivity.java when in reality MainApplication.java has onCreate() method. So do I need to insert it in MainApplication.java right?

Comment: it fails with this error: `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

Comment: Any idea why is it failing?

Comment: why mainactivity.java? OnCreate() in is mainapplication.java

Comment: `getWindow`  is available in `MainActivity` not in `ReactApplication`.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! Please upvote my question so more people can find it.